# Inequality involving derivative of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Let $D = B(0,1) \subset \mathbb{C} $ a disc, $f$ holomorphic on $D$. Show that $$ 2|f^{'}(0)| \le \sup_{z, w \in D} |f(z)-f(w)|$$ 
Furthermore, there is equality if and only if $f$ is linear.

Any hint ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $d=\sup_{z,w\in D}|f(z)-f(w)|$.

The inequality is from the Cauchy's integral formula,

$$f'(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z^2}dz,$$

By change of variable $z=-\zeta$,

$$
f'(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac{-f(-\zeta)}{\zeta^2}d\zeta.$$

Thus, 
$$2f'(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac{ f(z)-f(-z)}{z^2}dz.$$

Taking absolute value, 
$$
2|f'(0)|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\gamma} \frac{d}{|z|^2} |dz|=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{d}{r^2}2\pi r=\frac{d}{r}. $$
where $\gamma$ is a circle centered at $0$ with radius $r$ for all the integrals above.

Since $r<1$ is arbitrary, we have $2|f'(0)|\leq d$.

For the equality case, refer to [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01601942) by A. Pfluger.

Comment: is there a free link to the paper ?